# Can shares for sale be shorted?

Tags: shorting-securities

If I put my shares up for sale at a limit price (and good till cancelled), can they be shorted while my order is open?

Comment: Shorted by whom? By the broker without your knowledge or by another order inputed by you?

Answer (score 1):

In general, your broker could lend your shares to someone else for shorting or various other purposes.  But in general that's not something you would have to worry about, as the broker would be responsible for making delivery of the shares to whoever you sold them to, which might involve calling the shares back from loan, borrowing shares from another broker, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a cash account, your shares cannot be loaned out.

If it's a margin account, your broker can loan them (unless you have signed a loan exempt restriction).  However, this does not affect your ability to sell your shares.  And if you do sell them, it's your broker's responsibility to deliver the shares to the buyer.